# Modulus problem (Complex Number)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If complex number $z(z\neq2)$ satisfies the equation : $z^2=4z+\lvert z\rvert^2+\frac{16}{\lvert z\rvert^3}$, then what is the value of $\lvert z\rvert^4$?

**My try:** *I tried to take $z=x+iy$ and solved for the value of $\lvert z\rvert^4$ but everytime ended up getting a value greater than $9$.*

**Hint**- The answer lies between $0$ and $9$ , both included.

Comment: So can you show your work? Are you sure you typed up the problem correct? Please check the signs

Comment: actually i cant at the moment , but on substituting $z=x+iy$, i got $x=2$, so whatever my $y$ would be , my $\lvert z\rvert^4$ would already come out to be greater than $9$.

Comment: I need to think about this one, made a mistake myself :) I was actually thinking of writing $z$ as $re^{i\theta}$ and then plug in. The absolute value would be just $r$

Comment: lol , okay bro, take your time.

Comment: I concur with your earlier remark. I find the b-value to be at least $10$ to satisfy the given equation which puts $|z|^4$ way above $9$. So something isn't right here. (Leaving office now...)

Comment: Since this came up as a Review Audit, let me Comment that it doesn't make sense to ask for a complex number $z$ to be "between $0$ and $9$" unless you actually mean that $z$ is a *real number*.  This turns out to be consistent with the solution offered below.

Answer (score 4):

This question CAN be solved by assuming $z=x+iy$, where $x$ and $y$ are reals.

The given equation can be written as $$z^2-4z= |z|^2+ \frac{16}{|z|^3}$$

Plugging in $z=x+iy$ and

$$x^2-y^2 +2ixy -4x-4iy=x^2+y^2 + \frac{16}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^3}$$

taking the complex terms to one side, we obtain$$2iy(x-2)=2y^2+4x+\frac{16}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^3}$$

But if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, then the LHS cannot be equal to the RHS, as one is a real number and the other is a complex number . This means the LHS must be zero.

$\implies y=0$ or $x=2$.

First lets check for $y=0$. The equation reduces to
$$4x+\frac{16}{|x|^3}=0 \implies x=-\sqrt2$$

Hence 
$z=-\sqrt2$

$|z|^4 = 4$

**NOTE**: $x$ cannot be equal to $2$, because then, the expression can have no real value for $y$.(you can check this yourself)

Comment: +1) Never thought about the $y=0$ possibility, kept focusing on $x=2$